# It is possible to get keys from $_GET in php?

Tags: php

I just ask if it is possible to get keys from $_GET ...

I want to do a switch statement like

```
switch($_GET key)  //here I don't know
{
   case "login": .... break;   //if "login" key exists in $_GET then show page.
   ....
}
```

Sorry for idiot question

Comment: You should know the key in advance?

Comment: Yes, I should to know it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`array_keys();` will return an assoc array of keys from the passed param.

```
$arrKeys = array_keys($_GET);//$arrKeys will now contain all keys of $_GET (as an array)
```

Take a look at: [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

If you already know the key, and want the value of a specific element from the key, do this:

```
echo $_GET['myKey'];//which will print the value of the 'myKey' element
```

Answer (score 7):

You can iterate array and key with a simple for loop.
`$_GET` is nothing more than an associative array(it uses strings as array indexes).

with a `foreach($_GET as $key => $value)` php will split out each entry in the array in the corresponding array key in `$key` and array value in `$value`.

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
     {
     if($key === 'mykey')
         {
         // Do things with this key
         }
     if($key === 'login')
         {
         // Do login stuff etc...
         if($value === 'adminarea')
              {
              // login to adminarea
              }
         if($value === 'forum')
              {
              // Login to forum
              }
         }
     }
```

You can also use `array_key_exists`. This checks if a certain exists and if so you can do something with it.

```
if(array_key_exists('myKey', $_GET) && $value = $_GET['myKey']) {
    // do stuff with $value
}
```

But that is a bit cumbersome. Personally I prefer to use this function for simple arrays.

```
function array_get($array, $key, $default = null) 
{
    return (is_array($array) && array_key_exists($key, $array) ? $array[$key] : $default);
}
```

You can then do

```
if($value = array_get($_GET, 'myKey')) {
    // do stuff with mykey
}
```

Which is much cleaner and is descriptive.
It will always return null as default, or you can set your own default value.

```
 $music_intensity = array_get($_GET, 'intensity', 11);
```

Which then would return `11` as value to `$music_intensity` if no `$_GET` value was defined.